# how to permit and validate parameter in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm working on validating parameter passed in ruby controller/model as below. 
in the controller, i want to allow only to allow id and name parameter. and i want to pass that id and name parameter to the model class and validate they have acceptable values. i have following , is this a acceptable way to do it in ruby?

controller class

```
class PersonController 
  def create
    Person.find_By_person_id(check_params[:id], check_params[:name])
  end

  ...

  private

    def check_params
      params.permit(:id, :name)
    end
end
```

model class

```
class People
 class<<self
   def find_By_person_id(id, name)
      //validate id and name have values
      raise ArugmentError unless validate_params

      //calls another service to get the person

   end

   private
   def validate_params
      return false if id is not integer || id is less than zero || name is empty string 
   end 
 end
end
```

Comment: It's really a Rails thing, not a Ruby thing. Note that a comment in Ruby starts with `#`, not `//`. To your question directly, if `:id` and `:name` are all you are concerned about then what you show looks reasonable. It should have nothing to do with your model or validations you may perform there.

Comment: You could also look into using an ActiveModel-based form object, though this is an acceptable way of doing things. (Rewriting everything to use a form object as an answer is IMO beyond the scope of this site/question; but it gives you some terms you can search and try your hand at if it interests you, and come back for specific help implementing if you need.)

Comment: Yes, you pass the arguments to the model. By then they've been vetted via strong parameters as "legitimate" but not necessarily "valid". I was just pointing out that the validations inside your model are independent of that. You probably knew that though....

Comment: Create a method that permits a certain set of parameters, then use that method as your parameter list in a call such as `User.create(custom_params)`

Comment: Also you are rewriting `find` method for active record which will cause your more harm then help you because it will be very difficult to debug when you actually try to use `find` method as you learn the rails.

Comment: What is it that you are actually doing here? Are you writing a plain ruby MVC application or are you trying to learn rails?

Comment: @tblev - thanks for your comments. In the controller class, I have done something similar what you have suggested. but when I call a method on my model , I want to have both id and name as parameters in the model, not just custom_params as one argument.

Comment: @max - thanks. yes this is a MVC application but, people/user is not saved to the database. I call another service to get that data.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Active Record Validations (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) and use check for presence of the `:id` and `:name`. You model will look like so:

#### people.rb

```
class People < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

As for the id, Active Record generates a unique running id for any new record to be created, so I don't see any reason for you to need to validate it - unless you are passing another `:id` from the front end, in which case you should rename it so it won't conflict withe the `:id` for the record.

Comment: thanks for your reply. is the Active Record, like an ORM in ruby and tied to database. in this particular scenario, i call another service/API to get the people/user data.

Comment: Yes, it is the ORM. I presume you are using Ruby on Rails to build your application, isn't it so? Then there shouldn't be too difficult to implement whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: @Fahmiin- thanks. I have edited the method name after comments. my model method ->  def find_By_person_id(id, name) calls an API not database to get person data. so I'm not sure if i should use Active Record. secondly, I want to pass two parameters to my model method from my controller id and name as such =>   Person.find_By_person_id(check_params[:id], check_params[:name]), instead of just  one, as suggested  like this => find_By_person_id( check_params). calling this way  find_By_person_id(check_params[:id], check_params[:name]) calls check_params twice, which i want to avoid.

Comment: Just pass check_params as a single hash like so `find_By_person_id(check_params)` then in your model you can access it by `check_params[:id]` and `check_params[:name]`